# how to reduce multigraph to simple directed graph

Tags: graph, network-flow

Suppose there is a network with multiple edges, for any pair of vertices (u, v), the graph contains several directed edges from u to v and from v to u, each with its own capacity and weight.

How can I reduce this multigraph to a simple directed graph, with just one edge between u and v?

Note*: Not sure if this approach is right, I summed capacities and weights of the individual edges  between u and v and consolidated them into one super-edge from u to v, and one from v to u. But how do I further merge those two into just one edge between u and v and which direction should it point to?

Comment: This would depend on the purpose you're doing this transformation for.

Comment: The reduction will be used for a min-cost flow problem

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
    G = nx.Graph(G) #delete repeated edges
    G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges()) #delete self loops
    remove = [node for node,degree in G.degree().items() if degree < 1]
    G.remove_nodes_from(remove) 
    # these last two code lines delete nodes having degree 0 and are not
    # requied if all you want is to convert a multigraph into a simple graph
```